# how to use use properly in std:ostream& member, while "this" is a const?

Tags: c++, ostream

I have a class named "Subscriber" , which is inherited from a class 
named "Client", which contains the following lines of code , in "protected" :

```
std::ostream& messagesSink;

std::ostream&  getMessagesSink() {
    return messagesSink;
}
```

(messagesSink is initialized in the constructor of Subscribers)

and there is the following function-member in "subscriber" :

```
virtual void recieveMessage(const std::string& message ,
        const Topic& topic,
        const Client& client) const {
    messagesSink << "Topic: "<< topic
            << ". Sender: #" << client.getId() << ". Reciver: #"
            << getId() << ".Message: " << message;
}
```

the problem goes like this:in his current state, the code has no compilation errors, but if I replace the use of the member messagesSink in the function getMessagesSink(), as the code below, compilation errors appears:

```
virtual void recieveMessage(const std::string& message ,
        const Topic& topic,
        const Client& client) const {
    getMessagesSink() << "Topic: "<< topic
            << ". Sender: #" << client.getId() << ". Reciver: #"
            << getId() << ".Message: " << message;
}
```

my questions are:

1) what is the diffrence between before and after?

2) how to use properly the refrence to std::ostream ,while in a function that keeps "this" as a const?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getMessagesSink` is not marked `const`. `receiveMessage` is marked `const` so it can't call non-const member functions.

Comment: I've tried to change the return value of getMessagesSink to "const std::ostream&" but it just leads to complication errors of invalid conversion from "const char*" to int, long int, long long int , and so forth , and I dont understand that either .. why does the compiler expects to a "int" type variable? is there a way to pass the ostream type object, through a function?

Comment: This explains the problem well, but misses to propose a solution.

Comment: @Eden_Yosef: Just replace `getMessagesSink`: `std::ostream&  getMessagesSink() const { return messagesSink; }`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use non-const member functions inside const member functions of the same object. As far as the compiler is concerned you could be modifying the object when you call getMessagesSink().

I think getMessagesSink() should be const, if you cannot change that and you still want your function to be const you can do something like this inside receiveMessage().

```
Subscriber* self = const_cast<Subscriber*>(this);
std::ostream& messageSink = self->getMessagesSink();
```

Otherwise you have to either make your function non-const, or simply use the protected messagesSink object directly. Of course if the implementation of getMessageSink() changes, doing something to the std::ostream before returning a reference to it your code would likely break, or at least stop working as intended.

Comment: Meh. `const_cast` looks strange, and isn't actually needed. That's what `mutable` is for regarding class members.